# Google Chrome did not support backgroud-color: InfoBackground

Tags: html, css

I use CSS `background-color: InfoBackground`.

Normally, it is good for my website. But when my
Google Chrome automatically updates the latest version then this color is not working.

Comment: Ciao! It would be easier for this community to help you if you can add the code that is giving you troubles. Especially with HTML and CSS you can create snippets that are very easy to be investigated. Have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the W3 website](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords), the colour was deprecated meaning that it's essentially up to the discretion of browser vendor's to support. It would appear that Google has chosen to no longer support it as a valid colour name.

You'll have to replace it with an actual hex code or named colour.

Comment: And that makes sense as those color variables are 'MS Windows' windows specific...

Answer (score 1):

InfoBackground is now deprecated, according to [the w3 wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords). This means it's up to the browsers to support them or not. Google Chrome dropped support, and some other browsers probably will soon.

It is a very old property. Please consider using either a [HEX color code](https://htmlcolorcodes.com/) (e.g. #ffffff for white, #000000 for black), [RGB()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgb) (e.g. rgb(0,0,0) for black), or the supported [color keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color_keywords) (e.g. red, blue, aliceblue, white, black).

Also, see the [CSS deprecation list](https://css-tricks.com/list-of-depreciated-elements-still-in-widespread-use/) and [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same problem. Fix is to use actual hex code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).